# how to compare hash password with openssl_random_pseudo_bytes salt at php

Tags: php

```
//hash code
public static function make($string, $salt = ''){   
    return hash('sha256', $string . $salt);
}

public static function salt($length){
    return openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length);
}

public static function authenticate($username, $password)
{
    $encpassword = Hash::make($password);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '".$username."' AND password = '".$encpassword."' AND status = 1";
    $found = self::read($sql, PDO::FETCH_CLASS, __CLASS__);

    if ($found){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">
                  <strong>Found</strong>
               </div>';
    }else {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">
                  <strong>Not Found</strong>
               </div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: instead just use `password_hash` and `password_verify` http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php AND  http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php  Its a bad idea to roll your own encryption (hashing).  And doing user login systems without the proper security knowledge is not really advised either.

Comment: What I would do if I really wanted to do this is to tack the salt on the end of the password (in the DB) or save it in another field.  SHA256 is always 64 chars.  So you can use `substr` to remove the fixed length hash from the saved password before encrypting the incoming data (that way you have the salt and the hash)

Comment: A salt's purpose is not only to make the hash less guessable, it's to prevent attacks from dictionary lists, and rainbow tables (pre-complied hashes).  If it's known, such as an attacker gets a hold of the DB, it still complicates their task as they have to redo the rainbow table for each password.  They would be left with brute force or dictionary attacks (which they would need to modify, which can be coded in).... but anyway...

Comment: PS at the moment, it looks like your salt is `''` empty,

Comment: By the look of it, your SQL statement is potentially open to SQL injection. Should you not use prepared statements at least?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off...

Instead just use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) AND  Its a bad idea to roll your own encryption (hashing). And doing user login systems without the proper security knowledge is not really advised either.

However, for the sake of argument (this won't work due to the prepared statement):

```
public static function make($string, $salt = ''){   
    if(empty($salt)) $salt = self::salt(rand(10,20)); //if you do this make sure the field is big enaugh
    return hash('sha256', $string . $salt).$salt; //add salt to end of password
}

public static function salt($length){
    return openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length);
}

public static function authenticate($username, $password)
{

    //prepare your queries!!!! (see below)
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND status = 1'; //do not look up the password
    /*
       other DB code here
    */
    $found = self::read($sql, PDO::FETCH_CLASS, __CLASS__);

    if($found){ //should check for only 1 row returned as usernames should be unique index in the DB
        $row_pass = substr($row['password'], 0, 64); //pull password from DB
        $row_salt = substr($row['password'], 64); //pull salt from password

         //security compare hashes, in a safe way
        if(hash_equals($row_pass,self::make($password, $row_salt))){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">
                      <strong>Found</strong>
                   </div>';
        }else {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">
                      <strong>Not Found</strong>
                   </div>';
        }
}
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php

A few notes

- your salt is empty `$encpassword = Hash::make($password);`
- I have no idea how you access the DB, so I just put `$row` in there.
- change the collation of the hash field to `UTF8-bin` or UTF8 binary, then it's case sensitive when you search(optional).
- Never lookup by password because of the above (an other reasons). It's not impossible to have 2 similar hashes where only casing is different.  In such a circumstance 1 user could login as another user.
- prepare your queries.

**SQLInjection** If I passed (Into your method authenticate)

```
  $username = "' OR 1 LIMIT 1 --";
```

I would bypass your login with this query (which is one of the most common types of attack)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '' OR 1 LIMIT 1 --' AND password = '".$encpassword."' AND status = 1";
```

The `--` is a start of a comment in SQL, so nothing after that matters, and `OR 1` is always true.  Which (with limit, which your not even checking for only 1 return row) would return 1 row (every time) and bypass your login as `$found` would be `true`.  Just one of many reasons not to create your own login system.

In other words I can now login to your site as anyone I want to by using LIMIT and OFFSET irregardless of how difficult you make the password.  Obviously something that should be avoided.

**Another way** is to save the salt separate and retrieve it from the table.  However there was no code as to how you initially make the password, and save it.  So I went this way.  Also, I am not going to go in depth on how to prepare queries properly, there are plenty of examples on how to do this and given the lack of code on how you use the DB, it's not useful.

As I said in the comments

> A salt's purpose is not only to make the hash less guessable, it's to prevent attacks from dictionary lists, and rainbow tables (pre-complied hashes). If it's known, such as an attacker gets a hold of the DB, it still complicates their task as they have to redo the rainbow table for each password. They would be left with brute force or dictionary attacks

The idea with a salt is to give each password something different, then an attacker cannot use a huge DB of compiled hashes (rainbow table) to get the password.  It also complicates dictionary attacks (from outside the site) by making it not a sensible word.

In the case of a rainbow table, even if the attacker knows the salt it doesn't help them at all (they would need to recompile all the hashes in the rainbow table for each password, at that point the attacker is better using one of the two following methods).  In the cases a dictionary table, they must include the salt exactly the same way and the same in the case of brute force (which they may not know, even if they have the salt).  Even if they know both of those things, they are no better off then if you never salted it.  Worse because it virtually eliminates the rainbow table, unless it's a very targeted attack.  And as I said even in that case by the time they redo the rainbow table they could just brute force it.

So the point of the above, is the security from a salt doesn't come from it being known/unknown to an attacker.  Hence it's safe to store in the DB, because if an attacker can get the DB they probably own your server anyway, and you have bigger problems.  And it doens't help them because worst case they can brute force it, but not use rainbow tables and it complicates dictionary attacks even when it's known.

hope that all makes sense.